# C++ setting multiclass project promlem

Tags: c++, class, object, segmentation-fault

I have segmentation fault problem with my multiple class files project.

Without making empty classes and then pointers I get "XXX does not name a type" error.

How can I fix this or do this another way? I can not make class AA in class A.

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A a;

int main() {
    while(true) {

    }
    return 1;
}
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

class AA;

#include "AA.h"

class A {
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    AA *aa;
    void run();
};

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"


A::A() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

A::~A() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void A::run() {
    aa->run();
}
```

AA.h

```
#ifndef AA_H_
#define AA_H_

#include <iostream>

class AA {
public:
    AA();
    virtual ~AA();

    void run();
};

#endif /* AA_H_ */
```

AA.cpp

```
#include "AA.h"

AA::AA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

AA::~AA() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void AA::run() {
    std::cout << "1";
}
```

Comment: We are not going to unpack a zipfile to look through your code. Provide a minimal example that exhibits your problem, show it here. Then we might consider it.

Comment: When you have a problem with code that you can't solve, please reduce it to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), then post it here. You can't expect people to download zip files from third party websites and dig through your code to debug it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is an include of AA.h in A.cpp.

This is a quite common scenario. Whe your interface needs one thing and your implementation needs other stuff.  Not all includes should to be done in the .h file. Also this should not produce a segfault, it should be not compiling.

On the same note, you are including iostream in the .h file, you are using it in the .cpp file, why not include it there instead?

REREAD: You are not constructing your aa object. 
issue a

```
aa = new AA();
```

or similar in your constructor. Currently you are trying to access an object that has not been constructed.

Comment: Is this not being picked up by its inclusion in A.h ???

Comment: Missed that, yes it should.  Is it a compiler error or a segfault?

Comment: Also the forward declaration of class AA; is unnecessary with the inclusion.

Comment: Ok... Now this can't reproduce my problem, but in original program it still occurs. I will try to cause it in another sample and I will update my question.

Comment: @JakobekS See if you can remove the pointer and add a simple AA aa member instead. Usually a good design and way less error prone.

Comment: When I try to make normal var I get "field 'XXX' has incomplete type"

Comment: @JakobekS Yes, that is your problem, not the segfault, I would venture for a guess.  If you can include the header for the type you are good. Do not do forward declarations if you don't have to. You might have a circular reference.

Comment: When I got pointers I can't launch my program and get Segmentation fault in console. I can't reproduce this problem, do links to git are more welcome?

Comment: No, please try my suggestions, perhaps a new question. We are appreciative of easy to understand questions, so we can apply our expertise directly. Not so much of links and hidden variables.

Comment: Without forwarding declarations I get "'XXX' does not name a type", with it "field 'XXX' has incomplete type", pointer cause Segfault. I had included headers to my classes all the time.

Comment: I had error in init of few pointers, fixed now. You answer guided me to it. Thx :)